# Can I tell 'split' to not split lines?

Tags: macos, file-management

I have a large text file, that I need to split into a series of smaller (under 1MB) files.  It seems that `split` is what I want here.

However, if I try the following (using 900k as the limit to give some buffer before the hard limit of 1MB):

```
split -a 2 -b 900k total.sql createtables_
```

It will make each part exactly 900k (except the last part), most likely splitting lines at places where it splits the file.

So, is there a way to make it only split on line boundaries?  In other words, have it make the pieces as close as possible (without going over) the limit specified in the `-b` argument, ensuring it only splits on line boundaries?

Or is the only option to use the `-l` option to split to split based on line count, and just use trial and error to find the parameter than keeps all files under the limit?

Or is `split` not the right tool to be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split -l` is the best you can do natively on [Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/split.1.html). With [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html), you can use `split -C 900k`. You can install GNU coreutils on OSX, for example through [Darwion Ports](http://coreutils.darwinports.com/) or [Fink](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/coreutils) or [MacPorts](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/sysutils/coreutils).

Comment: coreutils is also available with Homebrew, which is a pretty solid package manager.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up installing GNU coreutils from Macports, and I am all set now.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what version of `split` you're using, but have you tried the `--line-bytes=BYTES` option?  On my system it can also be entered as `-C BYTES`.

Comment: I am using the version that is included in Mac OS 10.6 (I couldn't find a version number, but the man page lists Aug. 21, 2005 as the date).  My version doesn't accept `-C` or `--line-bytes` options.

Comment: The man page for mine shows `split 5.97  February 2010`. I'm not too familiar with Mac OS, but it is Unix based so you may be able to install a newer version of `split`.

Comment: Unix-based, yes, but BSD-based, while you're using GNU-based Linux. There are many differences between dialects of Unix-like systems often falling roughly under BSD, System V and GNU. While there's plenty of overlap and cross-pollination, "newer" isn't necessarily a well-defined delineator due to philosophical differences. As Gilles points out, on a Mac you have the option of installing GNU utilities side-by-side with the native ones.